# How to improve cubejs preagregations creation process? (its taking too long to build preaggs even with partitionGranularity)

Tags: javascript, sql, performance, analytics, cube.js

We are having trouble with the preaggregations creation performance. We currently have specific *filters* for the data for each one of our clients, and we generate different cubes for each one of them by extending a base cube (called `Metrics`) and defining a segment that represents those filters.

To summarize, we have a `Metrics` base cube, and we generate dynamic cubes `MetricsA, MetricsB, MetricsC` for clients `A, B, C`. Each one of these cubes has a segment that we call `z`, which contains a specific SQL query for each of our clients. The data to build the segment is retrieved from our API using `asyncModule`, and then we extend the `Metrics` cube to generate all the clients specific cubes by overriding the `z` segment with the client's `filter`.
By doing this, when a client queries the cube service, the data retrieved will come from their specific cube, with the data already filtered (by the enforced `z` segment).

This Metrics cube is built by joining large tables, so we also added a `partitionGranularity` (monthly) to reduce the size of the preaggregations, but they are still taking too long to build (> 10 minutes).
We need to edit the specific query that the cube service submits to create the preaggregation tables, so we only keep the rows with the `z` segment = 1 (because that is the relevant data), or at least we want to be able to rearrange/modify the query to improve performance. Which is the best place to do such changes? or what is the recommended practice to intervene this process?

Answer (score 1):

There're two approaches you can use to leverage pre-aggregations in multi-tenant environments.

1. Override `sql` for each customer cube such as `OrdersC1`, `OrdersC2`, etc. In this case all pre-aggregations defined in base `Orders` cube will be inherited. Each customer cube will have it's own set of pre-aggregations. It means if there're `N` customers and `M` pre-aggregations then `N * M` pre-aggregation tables should be built which can be costly in some scenarios.

```js
cube(`Orders`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM orders`,

  preAggregations: {
    date: {
      type: `rollup`,
      measureReferences: [someMeasure],
      dimensionReferences: [someDimension],
      timeDimensionReference: date,
      granularity: `month`
    },
    // ...
  }
});

cube(`OrdersC1`, {
  extends: Orders,
  sql: `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customer_id = 'C1'`,
});
```

2. Use tenant field as a dimension of rollup. Every segment can be converted to dimension which provides an opportunity to use single rollup table for all customers. To route requests to right tenant data [queryTransformer](https://cube.dev/docs/@cubejs-backend-server-core#options-reference-query-transformer) can be used.

```js
cube(`Orders`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM orders`,

  // ...

  dimensions: {
    // ...

    customerId: {
      sql: `customer_id`,
      type: `string`
    }
  },

  preAggregations: {
    date: {
      type: `rollup`,
      measureReferences: [someMeasure],
      dimensionReferences: [customerId, someDimension],
      timeDimensionReference: date,
      granularity: `month`
    },

    // ...
  }
});
```